# How to remove newline created by { % if %} in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am generating email using email template in django.

email_template.txt

```
Some random string
Some other string

-----------------------------------------

{% if 'firstname' in data %}firstname: {{data['firstname']}}{% endif %}
{% if 'lastname' in data %}lastname: {{data['lastname']}}{% endif %}
{% if 'dob' in data %}dob: {{data['dob']}}{% endif %}
{% if 'route' in data %}route: {{data['route']}}{% endif %}
{% if 'mobile' in data%}mobile: {{data['mobile']}}{% endif %}
{% if 'mail' in data%}mail: {{data['mail']}}{% endif %}
```

I used `spaceless` but it did not work.
In some cases if condition in template is not true then it gives new line.
How can I stop the extra new line if condition is not true.

Comment: You can put the items in the text fields, apply CSS on the fields such that if something is empty then it should not give an extra line using CSS. or you can also try ```{% else % } {%endif%}``` option with nothing in the else statement. probably it will not give a new line.

Comment: My files are in `.txt` format. How can i apply css on them and i tried with `{% else %}`, it did not work.

Comment: You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed:
```
{% for item in seq -%}
    {{ item }}
{%- endfor %}``` read here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/